# jQuery Validate image extension case

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate to validate image upload extension. Right now I have something like:

```
$("#photo").rules("add", {
        accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|"
    });
```

The problem is that this would only accept if the extension is lower case. I could do

```
$("#photo").rules("add", {
        accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|JPG|JPEG|PNG"
    });
```

But I would like this to work even if the extension is jPG or JPg. I tried this regex:

```
 accept: "/\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i"
```

Don't know if my regex is wrong or if the plugin just doesnt accept regex. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Wrong rule.  Those are file extensions, not mime types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`accept` is only for mime types.

You need the `extension` rule if you want to specify by file extension.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

Comment: I guess if I do image/* that would work with the accept rule, right?

Comment: @raygo,  read the docs!  That's also the default:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't need bother jQuery to validate image extention.

If you don't care about case-sensitivity, you just need to use `accept` attribute of `<input>` to do it, just like this

`<input type="file" name="pic" accept=".png, .jpg">`

but this solution has some compatibility limitation, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility